# Flutter: How to get updates of child Stream builder inside its parent?

Tags: flutter, provider

I have a Flutter page that consists of a Widget called: **VisitsHistory** , which has 2 child widgets called **VisitsList** & **Statistics**

The child widget "VisitsList" has a streambuilder that gets data from firestore and renders a list of cards.

I want the data stream that comes from the streambuilder to continuously update the "statistics" Widget. They both share the same parent (Visits History).

I tried using callbacks from the Streambuilder to notify the parent and then the parent calls SetState(), but that gave me an error : `setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build`

I understand the reason for the error is that I made the callback before the streambuilder returned what it's supposed to build, but where else can I put the callback so that I can guarantee that the build is done and finished and then it's safe to call setState() in parent ?

N.B.: I'm using Provider as my state management

Here's a snippet from the VisitsList Widget/StreamBuilder

```dart
    class VisitsList extends StatelessWidget {
      final Function getDebtDataCallback;
      VisitsList(this.getDebtDataCallback);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: doctorprovider.getVisitsHistory(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return new CircularProgressIndicator();
              default:
                if (snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) {
                  return Text(
                    "No Visits yet",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  );
                } else {
                  //CALLBACK IS HERE 
                  getDebtDataCallback(snapshot);
                  return new ListView( ......
```

Comment: If your child widget is not in a separate class then you can wrap the parent widget in the StreamBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a value updater to push values into the parent? Flutter team created a stock example application which demonstrate this feature.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/stocks

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

In the child, you need this boilerplate

```
class StockSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  const StockSettings(this.configuration, this.updater);

  final StockConfiguration configuration;
  final ValueChanged<StockConfiguration> updater;

  @override
  StockSettingsState createState() => StockSettingsState();
}

class StockSettingsState extends State<StockSettings> {
void _handleBackupChanged(bool value) {
    sendUpdates(widget.configuration.copyWith(backupMode: value ? BackupMode.enabled : BackupMode.disabled));
}

void sendUpdates(StockConfiguration value) {
    if (widget.updater != null)
      widget.updater(value);
}
```

In the parent, you pass down a configuration updater for the child to call the parent's `setState`.

```
class StocksAppState extends State<StocksApp> {
  StockData stocks;

  StockConfiguration _configuration = StockConfiguration(
    stockMode: StockMode.optimistic,
    backupMode: BackupMode.enabled,
    debugShowGrid: false,
    debugShowSizes: false,
    debugShowBaselines: false,
    debugShowLayers: false,
    debugShowPointers: false,
    debugShowRainbow: false,
    showPerformanceOverlay: false,
    showSemanticsDebugger: false
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    stocks = StockData();
  }

  void configurationUpdater(StockConfiguration value) {
    setState(() {
      _configuration = value;
    });
}

routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
         '/':         (BuildContext context) => StockHome(stocks, _configuration, configurationUpdater),
         '/settings': (BuildContext context) => StockSettings(_configuration, configurationUpdater)
},
```